rigid body is not working 4.2

0 frames in memory (0 B), cache is outdated!
I put it on Frame 1 and tried it, but it didn't bake.
I turned off rigidbody world and turned it back on, but it still doesn't bake.
I don't know why it's not working


You have Animated enabled on the rigid body object, but have not set any keyframes for animation. If you enable this option, the object will not be simulated and only move if you animate it.

Apart from that, you are currently not on a "real" frame. Your timeline shows you are on frame 1.11 instead of 1. If you set it to a full frame number, the simulation can be baked.

I do not know why you felt the need to enable showing subframes, but if you do not really need it, I would recommend to turn them off because many things only accept full frames as input, subframes are calculated under the hood.
If you enabled them by accident, here you can disable them: go to the Timeline, and under Playback disable Show Subframes.


I didn't know I had to press the keyframe. The reason I pressed subframe and anything else was because the timeline indicator on dual monitor was out of sync. Thanks for letting me know.

@novacrown You don't need keyframes for rigid body simulations. You only need them for manual animations. But when you set the rigid body to Animated you tell Blender (simply spoken): "Do not simulate it with physics, let me animate it."

Ok. I understand it. Thank you!
